# Ошибка в алгоритме выявление 2ух минимальных чисел в массиве

Tags: java, алгоритм

Формат ввода
Первая строка входного файла содержит целое число N — количество дроидов (), вторая строка — N целых чисел.
Формат вывода
Выведите два числа: первым — наименьший серийный номер дроида (которого поэтому следует утилизировать в первую очередь), а вторым — второй по минимальности.

Я написал код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = in.nextInt();
    int[] droids = new int[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        droids[i] = in.nextInt();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (droids[i] < min) {
            min = droids[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                if (droids[i] != droids[j]) {
                    if (min <= droids[j]) {
                        if (droids[j] < min1) {
                            min1 = droids[j];
                        }
                    }

                }


            }

        }


        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(min1);


    }
}
}
```

когда мы вводим во вторую входную строку 2 одинаковых числа, то он выводит только одно, например если мы введем 1 22 1 выведет 1,22 не понимаю почему, ведь я думал, что это исключу этой строкой `if (droids[i] != droids[j])`

Примечания:
     При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться стандартными функциями и методами min, index, sort, sorted и т. д.

Естественно, можно пользоваться функциями min, max, которые принимают два числа.

Comment: отсортируйте массив и возьмите 2 первых элемента

Comment: забыл добавить: При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться стандартными функциями и методами min, index, sort, sorted и т. д.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q: Решать тривиальную O(n) задачу через O(n log n) алгоритм? Зачем?

Comment: @AnT ну да, тут даже стоит тег алгоритм, признаю, тут был не уместен комментарий про сортировку. Зачем так решать такую тривиальную задачу? - Чтобы не думать над такого рода кодом, когда его встретишь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цикл в цикле. Да-a-a. Компьютер старательно жужжит и греет плохоприспособленное помещение. Можно сделать в лоб - за два прохода, запомнив индекс первого минимума. Но мы сделаем за один.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  int current = droids[i];
  if (current < min) {
    min1 = min;
    min = current;
  } else if (current < min1) {
    min1 = current;
  }
}
```

```js
var droids = [1, 22, 1];
var a = droids.length;
var min = min1 = 4e9;

for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  var current = droids[i];
  if (current < min) {
    min1 = min;
    min = current;
  } else if (current < min1) {
    min1 = current;
  }
}

console.log(min, min1);
```

*PS: Неплохой вопрос для интервью.*

Comment: `PS: Неплохой вопрос для интервью.` На какую позицию?  Меня, например, года 4 назад на модификации Левенштейна завалили :)