# Пересекаются ли прямоугольники?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Первая строка входных данных содержит четыре целых числа

Вторая строка содержит четыре целых числа

Выведите “Yes”, если заданные прямоугольники имеют хотя бы одну общую точку, и “No” в противном случае.
Есть такой код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int matchesCount = 0;

    int[] angle = new int[4];
    int[] angle2 = new int[4];
    boolean[] secondMatches = new boolean[angle2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < secondMatches.length; i++) {
        secondMatches[i] = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < angle.length; i++) {
        angle[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < angle2.length; j++) {
        angle2[j] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for (int firstElement : angle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < angle2.length; i++) {
            if (firstElement < 0) {
                firstElement = 0;
            }
            {
                if (firstElement == angle2[i]) {
                    if (angle2[i] < 0) {
                        angle2[i] = 0;
                    }
                    {
                        if (!secondMatches[i]) {
                            secondMatches[i] = true;
                            matchesCount++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (matchesCount >= 1) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }


}
}
```

Проходит все тесты с открытыми значениями, с закрытыми где-то выдает не правильный ответ.

Условие задачи:
На плоскости даны два прямоугольника. Стороны прямоугольников параллельны осям координат (то есть стороны либо горизонтальны, либо вертикальны).
В этой задаче прямоугольник — это граница прямоугольника и его внутренность. Каждый прямоугольник задан координатами двух противоположных вершин.
Проверьте, имеют ли два заданных прямоугольника хотя бы одну общую точку (в частности, если прямоугольники касаются по стороне или даже по вершине, они имеют общую точку).

Пример:

Ввод:
1 6 4 3
2 2 9 4

Вывод:"Yes"

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965228/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5

Comment: Так прямоугольники или треугольники?=)

Comment: Строим прямоугольник, левая нижняя вершина которого задается максимумами координат исходных левых нижних вершин, а правая верхняя - минимумами координат правых верхних вершин. И смотрим - существует ли таковой. Вот и все решение...

Comment: Что такое открытые и закрытые значения? Приведите пример сломанного теста

Comment: @defaultlocale открытые значения - те, что видит пользователь. Закрытые - те, что не видит. соответственно, пример сломанного теста юзер дать не может, т.к. этот тест - закрытый

Comment: Есть 5 примеров ввода и вывода. Неправильный ответ на 7ом который я не знаю

Comment: @igor, в той задачи я разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: @georgiy110802 Пожалуйста. Создатели сайта предусмотрели для таких случаев знаки "галочка" слева от ответов.

Comment: @Igor не знал, извините. Сейчас поставил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прямоугольники НЕ пересекаются:
- если левый край первого лежит правее правого края второго
- или левый край второго лежит правее правого края первого
- или верхний край первого лежит ниже нижнего края второго
- или верхний край второго лежит ниже нижнего края первого

И соответственно пересекаются в случае, если ни одно из этих условий не выполняется. Получается четырёхэтажная, но несложная зависимость:

```
isIntersect = not ( (left1 > right2) or
                    ...
                  )
```

Comment: добавил в вопрос пример, если ваше решение все таки подходит, дайте знать. Буду разбираться сильнее в вашем ответе.

Comment: @georgiy110802 Это решение (как и мое) *не зависит* от входных данных и не может *не подходить* к ним.

Comment: Да, подходит. И ответ Igor тоже подходит.

Comment: Ок, буду разбираться. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3):

```
Xc_distance = abs(Xc1 - Xc2) // - расстояние между центрами
W_average = (W1 + W2) / 2    // - средняя ширина

if ((Xc_distance <= W_average) and (такое же условие для Y))
{
  // пересекаются
}
```

Comment: вы ответили на вопрос если бы вопрос не имел описания, если вам не лень посмотрите описание.

Comment: @georgiy110802 Что Вам непонятно в моем ответе?

Comment: не могли бы вы скинуть полный код? я не могу разобраться с инициализацией переменных

Comment: @georgiy110802 Нет. Не мог бы скинуть.

Comment: ладно, все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если координаты первого `fxl` (first x left), `fyb` (first y bottom), `fxr` (first x right), `fyt` (first y top), а второго `sxl` и т.д. - то условие перечечения

```
if (max(fxl,sxl) <= min(fxr,sxr) &&
    max(fyb,syb) <= min(fyt,syt)) {

    // Пересечение

}
```